# How to debug Camel Route builder in eclipse IDE?

Tags: debugging, apache-camel

I have written Camel Route build in Java DSL and now I wanted to debug it in eclipse IDE, my class look like

```
public class PMRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
UserProfileResponseProcessor responseProcessor=new UserProfileResponseProcessor();
         System.out.println("\n");
         System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
         System.out.println("           STARTED PROCESS MANAGER ROUTEBUILDER                          ");
         System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
try{
             from("cxf:bean:process-manager-ws?dataFormat=POJO").routeId("process-manager-route-userprofile").log( "This is ${in.header.operationName} operation called...." )
                    .log( "Entering inside the Choice with operation....${in.header.operationName}")
                    //.wireTap(RouterEndPoints.ENDPOINT_AUDITOR_QUEUE.value(),true, new PreWireTapProcessor())
                    .choice()
                        /**
                         * ##################################### ROUTE FOR USER PROFILE REQUEST ###########################################
                         */
                        .when(simple("${in.header.operationName} == 'retrieveUserProfile'"))
                            .to("log:?showAll=true&multiline=true")
                            .setHeader("OPERATION_NAME", constant("retrieveUserProfile") )
                            .process(pmRequestProcessor)
                            .log( "Setting header value to...."+constant(AuditActions.Actions.ACTION_GET_USER_PROFILE.desc()) )
                            .setHeader(RouteActions.Actions.OMGMEAT_ACTION_ID.desc(), constant(AuditActions.Actions.ACTION_GET_USER_PROFILE.desc())).convertBodyTo(UserProfile.class)
                            .to(RouterEndPoints.ENDPOINT_USERPROFILE_QUEUE.value()).process(responseProcessor)
                        .when(simple("${in.header.operationName} == 'addUserProfile'"))
                            .log( "Setting header value to...."+constant(AuditActions.Actions.ACTION_ADD_PROFILE.desc()) )
                            .setHeader(RouteActions.Actions.OMGMEAT_ACTION_ID.desc(), constant(AuditActions.Actions.ACTION_ADD_PROFILE.desc())).convertBodyTo(UserProfile.class)
                            .to(RouterEndPoints.ENDPOINT_USERPROFILE_QUEUE.value()).process(responseProcessor)
.end()
 }catch(Exception exc){
             ApplicationLogger.error("PMRouteBuilder.configure():Exception while configure the route for 'cxf:bean:process-manager-ws?dataFormat=POJO'",exc);
         }
```

I am able to see the log is getting printed but is there any way to put the debug point(breakpoint) and debug this Route builder?

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-debug-my-route.html

Answer (score 1):

Additionnaly to the techniques described in the link provided by Claus, we also use the [Hawtio](http://hawt.io/plugins/camel/) console with the Camel plugin.

With this plugin, you can:

- Lists of all running Camel applications
- Detailed information of each Camel Context such as Camel version number, runtime statics
- Lists of all routes in each Camel applications and their runtime statistics
- Manage the lifecycle of all Camel applications and their routes, so you can restart / stop / pause / resume, etc.
- Graphical representation of the running routes along with real time metrics
- **Live tracing and debugging of running routes**
- Profile the running routes with real time runtime statics; detailed specified per processor
- Browsing and sending messages to Camel endpoint

I know you asked for Eclipse, but I think debugging step-by-step a DSL is not possible today, that is why we mainly use the Tracer enabled mode and in the last resort, use the Hawtio console for a step-by-step debugging.

Comment: Can we have any plugin which will integrate with Eclipse IDE?

Comment: We did not found any (free/non-commercial), for debugging route we make as I explained, and we are in a OSGI / ServiceMix Context which helps as well to use HawtIO.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique would be to use the JUnit of your IDE but you should modify your class a bit to be better testable:

Use properties for your endpoints, like changing

```
from("cxf:bean:process-manager-ws?dataFormat=POJO")
...
.to(RouterEndPoints.ENDPOINT_USERPROFILE_QUEUE.value()) // the two instances
```

with

```
from("{{from.endpoint}}")
...
.to("{{user.profile.endpoint.1}}")
...
.to("{{user.profile.endpoint.2}}")
```

and set the properties with the original values in your spring or bluprint file (depending which one you use).

After you can create a test in the test folder (src/test if using maven) called PMRouteBuilderTest with extends CamelTestSupport and with the following content:

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "direct:test")
protected Endpoint inputTest;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:userEndpointOne")
protected MockEndpoint destinationOne;

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:userEndpointTwo")
protected MockEndpoint destinationTwo;

@Test
public void testRoutingSampleToDestOne() throws Exception {

    destinationOne.expectedMessageCount(1);
    destinationTewo.expectedMessageCount(1);

    String body = "Anything that can make your test useful"
    sendBody(inputTest.getEndpointUri(), body);
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new PMRouteBuilder();
}

@Override
protected Properties useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    // Set your test properties here, those are examples
    props.put("from.endpoint", "direct:test");
    props.put("user.profile.endpoint.1", "mock:userEndpointOne");
    props.put("user.profile.endpoint.2", "mock:userEndpointTwo");

    return props;
}
```

You have to make your test to use the real beans as much as possible but sometimes when you cannot, you have to use a mock framework like Mockito to simulate method calls.
After that, you can execute your test in debug mode from your IDE and put breakpoints to the real processors you're using in the route.

I strongly recommend reading [this article about Camel testing](https://camel.apache.org/testing.html).

I postfixed the test class name with Test in sake of simplicity, but normally it should be named `PMRouteBuilderIT` as it test more than one class and should be executed in the Integration Test phase (mvn verify, with failsafe plugin).